# why the output said variable-sized may not be initialized?

Tags: c, arrays

```
 char letM[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 int nr;
 printf("enter a number between 7 and 15\n");
 scanf("%d", &nr);
 for (int j = 0; j<=nr-5; j++){
   char letter[j] = letM[rand()%26+1];
   printf("%c", letter);
 }
```

this code should be stamp nr-5 letter but when I run it, output say error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Comment: remove `[j]` from `char letter[j]`, you want your variable to be just a `char`

Comment: @EricPostpischil My bad. So, Jack_01, do you know that array indexing starts at 0 in C? You have an **array** overflow in `letM[rand()%26+1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare what `letter` is before using it. Here's an option if you want to store the letters.
Besides, when you print `letter` don't forget to print `letter[j]` instead.

```
     char letter[21];
     char letM[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
     int nr;
     printf("enter a number between 7 and 15\n");
     scanf("%d", &nr);
     for (int j = 0; j<=nr-5; j++){
       letter[j] = letM[rand()%26+1];
       printf("%c", letter[j]);
     }
```

Otherwise, as other suggested, here if you just want to print the letter, you don't even need a variable:

```
 char letM[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 int nr;
 printf("enter a number between 7 and 15\n");
 scanf("%d", &nr);
 for (int j = 0; j<=nr-5; j++){
   printf("%c", letM[rand()%26+1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`char letter[j];` defines `letter` to be an array containing `j` elements, each of which is a `char`. Because `j` is a variable, this is called a *variable length array*.

`char letter[j] = letM[rand()%26+1];` defines such an array and attempts to initialize it with the value of `letM[rand()%26+1];`. The C standard does not provide for initializing variable length arrays, and that is why you are getting an error message about it. (They must be given values via ordinary assignments statements or other means, not via initializers in declarations.)

You may have meant to declare `letter` to be a single `char`. In this case, change the code to `char letter = letM[rand()%26+1];`.

Additionally, `letM[rand()%26+1]` indexes the array incorrectly. In C, indices start with zero, so you should not add one. Use `letM[rand()%26]`.